# Update query not working for database in the same file as the vba code

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am new to writing sql in excel vba and I am trying to update certain values in a table range present in the same workbook as the vba code. However, I am encountering an error which says **"Operation must use an updateable query"**. Could someone please help me resolve this. Following is the code I wrote:

Public Sub OperationOnCn()

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim conn As Connection
Dim strsql As String
Dim strConn As String

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"


Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
wksInput.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Name = "rngInput"

conn.Open strCon

strsql = "Update rngInput set Salary=10000 where Branch='Delhi'"
rs.Open strsql, conn

wksOutput.Range("A1:Q1000").ClearContents

For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count

 wksOutput.Range("A1").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name

Next

wksOutput.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
conn.Close
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a Jet-Connection instead of writing directly from wksInput to wksOutput?

F.e. by using the `Range.Copy` - Method?

Beneath that, it seems to me, that you wanted to SELECT from wksInput and write to wksOuput, but your strsql is an UPDATE-Statement. So what should happen here, when you execute this?

Comment: Hi Oratom..Thanks for taking out your time and responding. I can very well use range.copy to put the data from one sheet to another but the reason to use SQL is that I am trying to learn on how to use SQL in excel. What I am intending to do here is update the salary column in recordset and then pasting it to wksOutput. Please let me know if I am unclear.

Comment: have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/705470/Read-and-Write-Excel-Documents-Using-OLEDB ... here´s a complete sample of reading and writing Excel-Documents through OleDB